# After integrating Tapjoy sdk in iPhone app, how to show ads, video in UiViewcontroller?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, sdk, ads, tapjoy

In my iPhone application I have to integrate Tapjoy SDK, and want to show ads,videos. 
In Tapjoy SDK demo they are showing only the connection status but what about the ads,videos. 
How to show this in UiViewController?
I need to show my app demo to my project manager, and I am not getting any solution on Tapjoy.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Before you can start showing ads, you will need to set up a currency in your app. If your app does not have a virtual currency, you will need to set up a non-rewarded currency and pass that id to our servers before you can show ads. You should also add your device into the test device list for the currency. Your app does not need to be live in the app store for you to test that the ads are showing up correctly.

The publisher SDK should have included a sample app for you to look at. You can also visit our knowledge center for more information (https://knowledge.tapjoy.com/en/integration/getting-started-guide-for-publishers).